# QuerySelectorAll not working with nth-child

Tags: javascript, selectors-api

I have the following html:

```
<div class="container">
  <div>Test1
    <div>Test1.1</div>
    <div>Test1.2</div>
    <div>Test1.3</div>
  </div>
  <div>Test2
    <div>Test2.1</div>
    <div>Test2.2</div>
    <div>Test2.3</div>
  </div>
  <div>Test3</div>
  <div>Test4</div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to get to 'Test 2' using this:

```
var secondChilds = document.querySelectorAll(".container div:nth-child(2)");
console.log(secondChilds[0]);
```

However, this gets me:

```
 <div>Test1.2</div>
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong? Thanks so much.

```js
var secondChilds = document.querySelectorAll(".container div:nth-child(2)");
console.log(secondChilds[0]);
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>Test1
    <div>Test1.1</div>
    <div>Test1.2</div>
    <div>Test1.3</div>
  </div>
  <div>Test2
    <div>Test2.1</div>
    <div>Test2.2</div>
    <div>Test2.3</div>
  </div>
  <div>Test3</div>
  <div>Test4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `nth-child()` starts counting from 1, unlike JavaScript which starts from 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`querySelectorAll()` is returning 3 divs. `Test1.2` is the second child of the `Test1` div. `Test2` is the 2nd child of the `.container` div. And `Test2.2` is the second child of the `Test2` div.

Since it returns them in the order that they appear in the DOM, the one that you want is `secondChilds[1]`, not `secondChilds[0]`.

If you only want to consider direct children of `.container`, not nested children, use `>`.

```js
var secondChilds = document.querySelectorAll(".container > div:nth-child(2)");
console.log(secondChilds[0].innerText);
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>Test1
    <div>Test1.1</div>
    <div>Test1.2</div>
    <div>Test1.3</div>
  </div>
  <div>Test2
    <div>Test2.1</div>
    <div>Test2.2</div>
    <div>Test2.3</div>
  </div>
  <div>Test3</div>
  <div>Test4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently your query ".container div:nth-child(2)" selects any type of div (including the nested ones) and returns you the second div (ie. Test 1.2). What you want only the immediate child of the `.container` div, so you can use the `>` to select the immediate children of parent.

So your query is supposed to be `.container > div:nth-child(2)`

```js
var secondChilds = document.querySelectorAll(".container > div:nth-child(2)");
console.log(secondChilds[0]);
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>Test1
    <div>Test1.1</div>
    <div>Test1.2</div>
    <div>Test1.3</div>
  </div>
  <div>Test2
    <div>Test2.1</div>
    <div>Test2.2</div>
    <div>Test2.3</div>
  </div>
  <div>Test3</div>
  <div>Test4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's actually index 1 what you are looking for.
`.container div:nth-child(1)`

```js
const secondChilds = document.querySelectorAll(".container div:nth-child(1)");

console.log(secondChilds[0]);
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>Test1
    <div>Test1.1</div>
    <div>Test1.2</div>
    <div>Test1.3</div>
  </div>
  <div>Test2
    <div>Test2.1</div>
    <div>Test2.2</div>
    <div>Test2.3</div>
  </div>
  <div>Test3</div>
  <div>Test4</div>
</div>
```